# How to craft in Unturned?

Tags: unturned

I've seen the wiki on hot to craft but how do I even grab things to move to the crafting area?

I try clicking and dragging but nothing happens, I try holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> and still nothing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I understand that you have read the [Wiki](http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/Crafting_Recipes), but have you watched the [video](http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/File:Unturned_Crafting_Guide_-_Crafting_Recipes_-_Baron%27s_Survival_Guide_Part_1-0)?

Comment: I did, I understood those but I just couldn't even pick items up

Comment: Well sorry I could not fix it, and I am glad that @longjacob1 did. Thanks for using SO :)

Comment: That's fine. Maybe someone else will be helped by the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hold items into your crafting inventory you must right click. I believe that's what you're asking due to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Like Minecraft, not just anything works. There are specific recipes for specific items.

To use the crafting grid, click once on the "Crafting" icon beneath your inventory. Once the grid is open, you can click once on the item you wish to use, then click again in the grid to drop the item. (Unturned uses a "Sticky mouse" drag and drop system).

Once you have all the necessary items in the crafting grid to make a certain item, you can click on "Craft", and the crafted item should replace the ingredients in the crafting grid. Drag and drop this back into your inventory.

[This video](http://youtu.be/6XmXjPUk4wA) has a wide range of recipes that will be useful in the game.

Answer (score 0):

Crafting is now much easier (as of version 3) - in the crafting tab it will automatically use materials that you're carrying, so just clicking on the recipe will craft that item.  [Check here](https://unturned.gameinfo.io) for a full list of what can be crafted.